# How to find all graph isomorphisms in FindGraphIsomorphism

Tags: graphs-and-networks, combinatorics

I found the second definition of the function `FindGraphIsomorphism` not working.

Here's the definition Mathematica 8 gives:

> `FindGraphIsomorphism[g1,g2]` finds an isomorphism that maps the graph
>   `g1` to `g2` by  renaming vertices. `FindGraphIsomorphism[g1,g2,n]` finds at
>   most n isomorphisms.

I tried the following two tests. Define a simple graph by

```
graph = AdjacencyGraph[{{1,0},{0,1}}];
```

Then running `FindGraphIsomorphism[graph,graph]` yields `{1->1, 2->2}`, this is good.

but running

```
FindGraphIsomorphism[graph,graph,2]
```

makes the Mathematica kernel dead. So I tried another graph,

```
graph = AdjacencyGraph[{{1,1},{1,1}}];
```

Running `FindGraphIsomorphism[graph,graph,2]` yielded error message:

> FindGraphIsomorphism::nonopt: Options expected (instead of 2)  beyond
>   position 2 in FindGraphIsomorphism[graph,graph,2]. An option must be a
>   rule or a list of rules.

My conclusion is that `FindGraphIsomorphism[g1,g2,n]` is a bug. Or am I wrong somewhere? What should I do to obtain a result like:

**Input:** `FindGraphIsomorphism[graph,graph,2]`

**Output:** `{{1->1,2->2}, {1->2,2->1}}`

---

Update:

It seems that the latest version of Mathematica does not support the third argument n in FindGraphIsomorphism. The form FindGraphIsomorphism[g1,g2,n] is no longer in the online documentation center. However, it exists in my older version 8.0.0, but fails to work.

I still want to know if there is any way to make it work: FindGraphIsomorphism[g1,g2] gives one isomorphism, but how to get the list of more than one, or, all isomorphisms?

Comment: I find nothing in the documentation of _Mathematica_ v.8.0.4 that indicates that `FindGraphIsomorphism` takes a third argument. What version are you running?

Comment: I am running version 8.0.0.0. You are right, I checked the online documentation center at the link http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FindGraphIsomorphism.html, and they don't have the third argument in the description. It seems that they tried to allow this extra argument in version 8.0.0, but took it back later. Maybe it is too hard to give the list of more than one isomorphisms?

Comment: The igraph library can compute *all* isomorphisms, or just count them.  You may try using that library.  If you are running Mathematica on Windows, and you would like to access igraph from it, you could use RLink and the R igraph interface.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Alternatively, you can use the Combinatorica package.

```
Block[{$ContextPath}, 
 Needs["Combinatorica`"]; 
 Needs["GraphUtilities`"]]

graph = AdjacencyGraph[{{1, 0}, {0, 1}}];

Combinatorica`Automorphisms@GraphUtilities`ToCombinatoricaGraph[graph]

(* ==> {{1, 2}, {2, 1}} *)
```

The return values are to be interpreted as vertex permutations.

---

Note:  In this answer I load Combinatorica without adding it to the context path (see `Block` above), to avoid masking `` System`Graph ``.  However, the `` GraphUtilities`ToCombinatoricaGraph `` function will unfortunately re-add it to the context path every time it is called.  If this bothers you, you can either modify the GraphUtilities package or wrap the culprit function using the [Villegas-Gayley trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5149656/695132) to restore the original context path after the function has run.

---

**Update:**

At least in version 10.0 and later, `FindGraphIsomorphism[g1, g2, All]` will correctly return all isomorphisms.

Once we have *one* isomorphism from `g1` to `g2`, finding the rest is equivalent to finding the elements of the automorphism group of `g1` (or `g2`).  This can be done using

```
GroupElements@GraphAutomorphismGroup[g1]
```

The elements are returned as permutations in the cycles representation.  It is convenient to transform them to other representation either by using [`Permute`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Permute.html) with `VertexList[g1]`, or by using [`PermutationList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PermutationList.html) (see two-argument form).

Since the automorphism group may have a very large number of elements, it is often more convenient to work with the group directly (`GraphAutomorphismGroup` and group theory functions) rather than explicitly listing its elements (`FindGraphIsomorphism`).

Comment: Good point to use `GraphUtilities\ToCombinatoricaGraph`. I noticed that similar to `Automorphisms`, the command `Isomorphism[g1,g2,All]` in `Combinatorica` gives all isomorphisms between the graphs `g1` and `g2`.

Comment: That localization of `$ContextPath`! +1

Answer (score 6):

I noticed that here you are looking for automorphisms.  You can use [Mark McClure's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/36/mark-mcclure) [igraph link](http://facstaff.unca.edu/mcmcclur/REU/2009/) to compute these.  I put an updated version of the link [here](https://bitbucket.org/szhorvat/iglink/overview).  This version will work with igraph 0.6.5.

The package is a little rough around the edges, but it'll do the job.

---

To get the package working, you'll need to compile the C source first.  On OS X, this is how to do it:

1. Install igraph.  If you have MacPorts installed, this is as simple as `sudo port install igraph`
2. Go to `IGLink/bin/Source` and edit the `Makefile`. Make sure the paths to Mathematica are correct.
3. From the terminal, run `make` in the same folder.
4. Copy the generated `igraph` binary to `IGLink/bin/MacOSX`.

---

After loading `` IGLink` `` (please see the included IGraph.nb on how to load it), you can do

```
graph = AdjacencyGraph[{{1, 0}, {0, 1}}];

(* convert to a suitable format for IGLink *)
edges = Rule @@@ EdgeList[graph];

IGAutomorphisms[edges]

(* ==> {{1 -> 1, 2 -> 2}, {1 -> 2, 2 -> 1}} *)
```

If you have a bigger graph, you may want to check `IGAutomorphismCount[edges]` to make sure `IGAutomorphisms` won't be returning a list that is two big to handle.

Also note that the graphs are considered to be undirected even though the edges are represented using `Rule`.

Comment: Awesome! Although it worked for my purposes "Rough around the edges" is a polite description. The package was originally written to help some REU students solve some specific questions in graph theory. Thus, the current available functionality is small and chosen for a specific task. But it is a start and should be easy to add to, for those familiar with C programming and MathLink. And, thanks to Szabolcs for getting the package to work with the latest version of igraph!

Comment: @MarkMcClure Here's a package that is a spiritual successor of the project (even though it's a reimplementation): http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/97233/12 :-)

Comment: Thanks for the info! I've not been using Mathematica of late but, if I find myself needing to study graph theory within Mathematica at some point, I'm sure I'll have a look.

Answer (score 2):

**Update:** Be sure to also check out [IGraph/M](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/97233/12).

```
IGVF2FindIsomorphisms[graph, graph]
```

We can also get the automorphism group:

```
IGBlissAutomorphismGroup[graph]
(* {{2, 1}} *)

GroupElements@PermutationGroup[%]
(* {Cycles[{}], Cycles[{{1, 2}}]} *)

PermutationList[#, 2] & /@ %
(* {{1, 2}, {2, 1}} *)
```

*Mathematica 10* also has this functionality built in:

```
$Version
(* "10.3.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (October 9, 2015)" *)

FindGraphIsomorphism[graph, graph, All]
(* {<|1 -> 1, 2 -> 2|>, <|1 -> 2, 2 -> 1|>} *)

GraphAutomorphismGroup[graph]
(* PermutationGroup[{Cycles[{{1, 2}}]}] *)
```

---

With apologies for the third, yet again independent answer, I recommend calling igraph through RLink using [this package](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/24544/how-can-i-conveniently-call-igraph-through-rlink) (only if you have v9 of Mathematica).  Please see the instructions on how to set up the package, then you can do:

```
graph = AdjacencyGraph[{{1,0},{0,1}}];
res = IGraph["graph.get.isomorphisms.vf2"][graph, graph]

Round[res+1]
```

This will give you the list of mappings (automorphism).

Some graphs have a huge number of these, so before retrieving all automorphisms, you can count them using `IGraph["graph.count.isomorphisms.vf2"][graph, graph]`