# Delete duplicates of isomerism

Tags: graphs-and-networks, chemistry

I written some code to generate all partens of $\ \mathrm{C_2H_5O}$, but theres some isomerisms need to be deleted.

Here's the raw output after `DeleteDuplicates`.

```
(*del=DeleteDuplicates@raw*)
del={{{"C",2}<->{"C",1},{"O",1}<->{"C",2},{"H",1}<->{"C",1},{"H",2}<->{"C",2},{"H",3}<->{"C",1},{"O",1}<->{"C",2},{"H",4}<->{"C",1}},{{"C",2}<->{"C",1},{"O",1}<->{"C",2},{"H",1}<->{"C",1},{"H",2}<->{"C",2},{"C",1}<->{"O",1},{"H",3}<->{"C",2},{"H",4}<->{"C",1}},{{"C",2}<->{"C",1},{"O",1}<->{"C",2},{"H",1}<->{"C",1},{"C",2}<->{"C",1},{"H",2}<->{"O",1},{"H",3}<->{"C",2},{"H",4}<->{"C",1}},{{"C",2}<->{"C",1},{"H",1}<->{"C",2},{"O",1}<->{"C",1},{"H",2}<->{"C",2},{"H",3}<->{"C",1},{"O",1}<->{"C",2},{"H",4}<->{"C",1}},{{"C",2}<->{"C",1},{"H",1}<->{"C",2},{"O",1}<->{"C",1},{"H",2}<->{"C",2},{"C",1}<->{"O",1},{"H",3}<->{"C",2},{"H",4}<->{"C",1}},{{"C",2}<->{"C",1},{"H",1}<->{"C",2},{"O",1}<->{"C",1},{"C",2}<->{"C",1},{"H",2}<->{"O",1},{"H",3}<->{"C",2},{"H",4}<->{"C",1}},{{"C",2}<->{"C",1},{"H",1}<->{"C",2},{"H",2}<->{"C",1},{"O",1}<->{"C",2},{"H",3}<->{"C",1},{"O",1}<->{"C",2},{"H",4}<->{"C",1}},{{"C",2}<->{"C",1},{"H",1}<->{"C",2},{"H",2}<->{"C",1},{"O",1}<->{"C",2},{"C",1}<->{"O",1},{"H",3}<->{"C",2},{"H",4}<->{"C",1}},{{"C",2}<->{"C",1},{"H",1}<->{"C",2},{"H",2}<->{"C",1},{"H",3}<->{"C",2},{"C",1}<->{"C",2},{"O",1}<->{"C",1},{"H",4}<->{"O",1}},{{"C",2}<->{"C",1},{"H",1}<->{"C",2},{"H",2}<->{"C",1},{"H",3}<->{"C",2},{"O",1}<->{"C",1},{"O",1}<->{"C",1},{"H",4}<->{"C",2}},{{"C",2}<->{"C",1},{"H",1}<->{"C",2},{"H",2}<->{"C",1},{"C",2}<->{"C",1},{"O",1}<->{"C",2},{"H",3}<->{"O",1},{"H",4}<->{"C",1}},{{"C",2}<->{"C",1},{"O",1}<->{"C",2},{"O",1}<->{"C",2},{"H",1}<->{"C",1},{"H",2}<->{"C",1},{"H",3}<->{"C",2},{"H",4}<->{"C",1}},{{"O",1}<->{"C",1},{"H",1}<->{"C",1},{"H",2}<->{"C",1},{"C",2}<->{"O",1},{"H",3}<->{"C",2},{"C",2}<->{"C",1},{"H",4}<->{"C",2}},{{"O",1}<->{"C",1},{"H",1}<->{"C",1},{"C",1}<->{"O",1},{"C",2}<->{"C",1},{"H",2}<->{"C",2},{"H",3}<->{"C",2},{"H",4}<->{"C",2}},{{"O",1}<->{"C",1},{"H",1}<->{"C",1},{"C",2}<->{"C",1},{"C",2}<->{"C",1},{"H",2}<->{"C",2},{"H",3}<->{"O",1},{"H",4}<->{"C",2}},{{"H",1}<->{"C",1},{"C",2}<->{"C",1},{"H",2}<->{"C",2},{"H",3}<->{"C",2},{"C",1}<->{"C",2},{"O",1}<->{"C",1},{"H",4}<->{"O",1}},{{"H",1}<->{"C",1},{"C",2}<->{"C",1},{"H",2}<->{"C",2},{"C",2}<->{"C",1},{"O",1}<->{"C",2},{"H",3}<->{"O",1},{"H",4}<->{"C",1}},{{"H",1}<->{"C",1},{"H",2}<->{"C",1},{"C",2}<->{"C",1},{"H",3}<->{"C",2},{"C",2}<->{"C",1},{"O",1}<->{"C",2},{"H",4}<->{"O",1}},{{"H",1}<->{"C",1},{"H",2}<->{"C",1},{"C",2}<->{"C",1},{"C",2}<->{"C",1},{"O",1}<->{"C",2},{"H",3}<->{"O",1},{"H",4}<->{"C",2}},{{"H",1}<->{"C",1},{"H",2}<->{"C",1},{"H",3}<->{"C",1},{"C",2}<->{"C",1},{"O",1}<->{"C",2},{"C",2}<->{"O",1},{"H",4}<->{"C",2}}}
show=Graph[#, GraphLayout->"SpringEmbedding",
  VertexStyle->{{"C",_}->Lighter[Black],{"O",_}->Lighter[Red],{"H",_}->LightBlue,{"N",_}-> Lighter[Blue]},
  EdgeStyle-> Darker@Green,VertexSize->{{"C",_}->0.7,{"O",_}->0.5,{"H",_}->0.4,{"N",_}->0.6}, 
  ImageSize->{210,200}]&;
Multicolumn@DeleteDuplicates[show/@del]
```

[image]

The last one is the same as blue ones (not the red one) in 2D. And `IsomorphicGraphQ` would delete all but first one.

How can I delete these duplicates one?

Just consider planar isomerism, and I also glad to see if anyone solved 
the stereo isomerism.

---

**Edit:**

I don't know why you can't reproduce this.

I restarted my Kernels and got the same results.

[image]

```
$Version
show=Graph[#,GraphLayout->"SpringEmbedding",
    VertexStyle->{{"C",_}->Lighter[Black],{"O",_}->Lighter[Red],{"H",_}->LightBlue,{"N",_}->Lighter[Blue]},
    EdgeStyle->Darker@Green,VertexSize->{{"C",_}->0.7,{"O",_}->0.5,{"H",_}->0.4,{"N",_}->0.6},
    ImageSize->{210,200}]&;
del={
    {{"C",2}<->{"C",1},{"O",1}<->{"C",2},{"H",1}<->{"C",1},{"H",2}<->{"C",2},{"H",3}<->{"C",1},{"O",1}<->{"C",2},{"H",4}<->{"C",1}},
    {{"C",2}<->{"C",1},{"H",1}<->{"C",2},{"O",1}<->{"C",1},{"H",2}<->{"C",2},{"C",1}<->{"O",1},{"H",3}<->{"C",2},{"H",4}<->{"C",1}},
    {{"C",2}<->{"C",1},{"O",1}<->{"C",2},{"H",1}<->{"C",1},{"H",2}<->{"C",2},{"C",1}<->{"O",1},{"H",3}<->{"C",2},{"H",4}<->{"C",1}}
};
Quiet@DeleteDuplicatesBy[show/@del,CanonicalGraph]
DeleteDuplicatesBy[show/@del,IsomorphicGraphQ]
```

These are {1,2,5} of last `del`.

If still have problems I may need to reinstall my Mathematica :).

Comment: I cannot reproduce your result by your code

Comment: 1. at the start of the code snippet you use `del=DeleteDuplicates@raw` but in the end you use `Multicolumn@DeleteDuplicates[show/@raw]`; what are we seeing `raw` or `del`? 2. `del[[{1, 2, 9, 12, 18, 20}]` **does not** match the presented output 3. there are rules about "N" which doesn't seem to be present - but that's not so important

Comment: [`DeleteDuplicates`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DeleteDuplicates.html) operates on lists but your `del` is **not** a simple list; perhaps you might be interested in [`DeleteDuplicatesBy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DeleteDuplicatesBy.html)

Comment: try `DeleteDuplicatesBy[del, IsomorphicGraphQ]` (there's nothing wrong with your installation as far as I can tell)

Comment: @user42582 ,sry, that's `del`... and I think `Multicolumn` should be read by column (at least in my mathematica). I've tried again and used `DeleteDuplicatesBy`.

Comment: you are correct about `MultiColumn`; `show /@ del[[{1, 5, 7, 12, 14, 20}]]` produces the correct graphs; my bad

Comment: Is filtering by coloured graph isomorphism acceptable for you?  Or do you need to take the spatial structure into account?  Filtering by coloured isomorphism should have been possible with [IGraph/M](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM), but there were some bugs that prevented it from working in this situation.  I fixed those bugs and plan to release a new version soon.  It looks like this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/4jsfU.png

Comment: Some notes about your update to the question, which I didn't read before commenting.  1. That should be `DeleteDuplicatesBy[graphs, CanonicalGraph]` or alternatively `DeleteDuplicates[graphs, IsomorphicGraphQ]`.  Note the difference between `DeleteDuplicates` and `DeleteDuplicatesBy`.  2. Mathematica 11.2 has a very nasty bug where all isomorphism functionality is broken on Windows (Mac/Linux are fine). How this could have gotten through Wolfram's testing is beyond me. The good news is that my package IGraph/M can fully replace the built-in isomorphism stuff ...

Comment: ... and works fine with M11.2 on Windows.  Unfortunately, `IGBlissCanonicalGraph` had a serious bug, which I corrected today. Expect a new release by tomorrow.

Comment: Possible duplicate:  https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/22813/9490

Comment: very closely related:  https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/121050/9490

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*The answer below requires [IGraph/M](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM) 0.3.96 or later. If you have an earlier version, please upgrade.*

If we only consider the connectivity of the atoms, not their spatial arrangements, we can remove duplicates based on graph isomorphism.  This can be done in one of two ways:

```
DeleteDuplicatesBy[graphs, CanonicalGraph]
```

or

```
DeleteDuplicates[graphs, IsomorphicGraphQ]
```

The first solution is preferable because it has linear complexity in the number of graphs/molecules, while the second is quadratic.

Unfortunately, in Mathematica 11.2 for Windows most of the isomorphism functionality is broken. (Earlier versions and Linux/Mac are not affected.)

There is also the major problem that the builtin isomorphism functionality does not currently support either multigraphs (multiple bonds between the same atoms) or vertex colouring (i.e. restricting mappings to between identical types of atoms).

---

IGraph/M provides some, but not all of this functionality.  Out of the box, it supports *either* isomorphism with vertex colouring (i.e. distinguishing atom types) *or* multigraph isomorphism, but not both simultaneously.  If you need both, you can map edge multiplicity to edge colours, and use `IGVF2IsomorphicQ`.

However, it seems to me that for this application, edge multiplicity can be ignored.  Let us thus focus only on vertex colours now.

IGraph/M requires vertex colours to be integers.  Let us start by transforming the atom names to integers, and storing the result in the `"Color"` vertex property. The following vertex map operator does this:

```
atomToNumber = <|"H" -> 1, "C" -> 6, "O" -> 8|>;

IGVertexMap[atomToNumber @* First, "Color" -> VertexList]
```

Before applying it, we need to get rid of multi-edges.  We can use [`SimpleGraph`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SimpleGraph.html) for that.  It needs to be applied *before* the above function because, unfortunately, it discards vertex properties.

Finally, we will use `IGBlissCanonicalGraph` instead of `CanonicalGraph`. It supports vertex colouring. We need to tell it which property contains the colours.

Putting all of it together,

```
graphs = show /@ del

atomToNumber = <|"H" -> 1, "C" -> 6, "O" -> 8|>;

DeleteDuplicatesBy[
 graphs,
 IGBlissCanonicalGraph[{#, "VertexColors" -> "Color"}] & @*
  IGVertexMap[atomToNumber @* First, "Color" -> VertexList] @*
  SimpleGraph
]
```

[image]

A slightly different way to accomplish the same is to forget about vertex properties and specify the colours as a plain list.

```
DeleteDuplicatesBy[
 graphs,
 IGBlissCanonicalGraph[{SimpleGraph[#], "VertexColors" -> atomToNumber /@ First /@ VertexList[#]}] &
]
```

Answer (score 6):

It is true that the built-in function `IsomorphicGraphQ` does not consider vertex color (atom types) or multi-edges (double and triple bonds).  It would be nice if there were an `IsomorphicMoleculeQ` function, but we can make do with an external library.

The [CDK java library](https://github.com/cdk/cdk) is easy to use, and [well-documented](http://cdk.github.io/cdk/2.0/docs/api/).  `JLink` makes it easy to use a java library without writing any java code.

Here is an example of how to use it for deleting duplicates based on chemical isomorphism.  In the code below, I first convert a bond list into an [AtomContainer](http://cdk.github.io/cdk/2.0/docs/api/org/openscience/cdk/AtomContainer.html), then use the [UniversalIsomorphismTester](https://cdk.github.io/cdk/1.5/docs/api/org/openscience/cdk/isomorphism/UniversalIsomorphismTester.html) class to compare the molecules.

First download the [latest release](https://github.com/cdk/cdk/releases/download/cdk-2.1/cdk-2.1.jar) of CDK.  Change the file path below to the downloaded location for your system.

```
<< JLink`

AddToClassPath["~/Downloads/cdk-2.1.jar"];
(* necessary to load this enum class separately *)
LoadJavaClass["org.openscience.cdk.interfaces.IBond$Order"];

$bondPattern = (UndirectedEdge | TwoWayRule)[{_String, _Integer}, {_String, _Integer}];

bondListToAtomContainer[bondList : {$bondPattern ..}] := 
  bondListToAtomContainer[bondList] =
   Block[{bonds, atomList, mol},
    (* convert each bond into a list of {{id1, id2}, bondorder} *)
    (* and make a list of atomic symbols for the atoms *)
    bonds = List @@@ bondList;
    bonds = Sort /@ bonds;
    atomList = Flatten[bonds, 1] // Union;
    atomList = Thread[atomList -> Range[0, Length@atomList - 1]];
    bonds = bonds /. atomList;
    bonds = 
     Tally[bonds] /. {{a1_, a2_}, n_} :> {{a1, a2}, 
        n /. {1 -> IBond$Order`SINGLE, 2 -> IBond$Order`DOUBLE}};
    atomList = atomList[[All, 1, 1]];
    (* now create an empty molecule, then add the atoms and bonds *)
    mol = JavaNew["org.openscience.cdk.AtomContainer"];
    Do[
     mol@addAtom[JavaNew["org.openscience.cdk.Atom", atom]],
     {atom, atomList}];
    Do[ 
     mol@addBond[ bond[[1, 1]], bond[[1, 2]], bond[[2]]],
     {bond, bonds}
     ];
    (* return the molecule *)
    mol];
(* now instantiate a UniversalIsomorphismTester *)
isomorphismTester := 
  isomorphismTester = 
   JavaNew["org.openscience.cdk.isomorphism.UniversalIsomorphismTester"];

(* Finally a function to test if two molecules, 
   represented by bond lists, are isomorphic *)
isomorphicMoleculeQ[bondList1 : {$bondPattern ..}, 
  bondList2 : {$bondPattern ..}] :=
 isomorphismTester@isIsomorph[
   bondListToAtomContainer@bondList1, 
   bondListToAtomContainer@bondList2]
```

If I define `del` and `show` as the list in the OP, I can use the 2-argument form of [`DeleteDuplicates`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DeleteDuplicates.html),

```
DeleteDuplicates[del,
 isomorphicMoleculeQ
 ]
(* {{{"C", 2} <-> {"C", 1}, {"O", 1} <-> {"C", 2}, {"H", 
    1} <-> {"C", 1}, {"H", 2} <-> {"C", 2}, {"H", 3} <-> {"C", 
    1}, {"O", 1} <-> {"C", 2}, {"H", 4} <-> {"C", 1}}, {{"C", 
    2} <-> {"C", 1}, {"O", 1} <-> {"C", 2}, {"H", 1} <-> {"C", 
    1}, {"H", 2} <-> {"C", 2}, {"C", 1} <-> {"O", 1}, {"H", 
    3} <-> {"C", 2}, {"H", 4} <-> {"C", 1}}, {{"C", 2} <-> {"C", 
    1}, {"O", 1} <-> {"C", 2}, {"H", 1} <-> {"C", 1}, {"C", 
    2} <-> {"C", 1}, {"H", 2} <-> {"O", 1}, {"H", 3} <-> {"C", 
    2}, {"H", 4} <-> {"C", 1}}} *)

show /@ %
```

[image]

A more efficient way to do this might be to convert each molecule into a canonical SMILES string, which the CDK can do quite well.